# A Periodic Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles, chemistry

*Entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #38: Reusing Information 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/fortnightly-topic-challenge-38-reusing-information-1)*

[image: Periodic Table of Elements... but perhaps a little more puzzly?]

Isn't it nice to have the same information to depend on, that you know will be reused? ... Wait, who said that you were getting that information?

Hint 1 (Incorrect Integers):

> What might that green arrow point out? [For the colourblind, the green arrow is the only arrow without a question mark underneath.]

Hint 2 (Weird Weights):

> I wonder why lithium has "CPU" under it, and whether that might help work out what the other weights mean.

Hint 3 (Incorrect Integers):

> There are exactly two of each '(1)', '(2)' and '(3)'.

Hint 4 (Incorrect Integers):

> The extraction to a word from this puzzle is similar to Weird Weights in the final step.

Hint 5 ([metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)):

> The letters in the grey circles at the top spell “meta” when rearranged.

Hint 6 ([metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)):

> This structure is very important to the metapuzzle, and may remind you of something else:
>  [image: Structure]

Hint 7 ([metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)):

> The above image specifically relates to ionic bonds.

Hint 8 ([metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)):

> What do the four circles represent in the “meta” at the top of the image, and what happens to the circles in an ionic bond?

Comment: May I know what is the question here?

Comment: @WaisKamal This is an [`enigmatic-puzzle`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/enigmatic-puzzle/info) and as such, it is up to us to determine which kind of puzzle this actually is, and therefore what the OP is requesting of us. I would assume it has something to do with duplicated information that isn't inherently obvious.

Comment: (rot 13, as always) Fbqvhz unf na vapbeerpg vagrtre, vg'f erny vagrtre fubhyq or ryrira

Comment: @tox123 Good theory. I won't disclose whether it's right or wrong at this point.

Comment: Also, I wonder why there are three fours, one of which is marked 4(2).

Comment: Oh man I really wanna know the answer to this question...

Comment: (if you find the time, do give us another hint :0)

Comment: The metapuzzle hints seem to indicate that rot13(fznyy pvepyrf ner ryrpgebaf, naq ngbzf tvir naq gnxr ryrpgebaf ("r") va na vbavp obaq. Gur neebjf ner sebz pyhrf gb fho-nafjref, fb V guvax fho-nafjref fubhyq tnva gur yrggre R.)

Answer (score 18):

Leaving a partial solution because I'm going to sleep soon

**Incorrect Integers**

Part 1

> Drawing lines through the pairs of numbers
>  [image]

Part 2

> each pair of lines intersect at one element
>
> ```
>  (1) | 18 | Argon  | Ar
>  (2) | 6  | Carbon | C
>  (3) | 8  | Oxygen | O
> ```

Answer

> This spells **arco**

**Weird Weights**

Part 1

> The 'atomic weights' of each element are pairs of atomic numbers. Each pair of elements shares a common letter which can be joined together to spell out the next clue.
>
> ```
> |    |     4 | lithium    |     6.94 | CPU  |   |
> |  1 | 17(2) | titanium   |   34.117 | SETS | S |
> |  2 | 10(1) | hexose     |   67.118 | HOOG | O |
> |  3 |     3 | sorbose    |   110.46 | DSPD | D |
> |  4 |     4 | luminance  |    47.56 | AGBA | A |
> |  5 |     5 | table      |   116.23 | LVV  | V |
> |  6 |  7(3) | iodine     |    85.20 | ATCA | A |
> |  7 |  4(2) | ostinato   |    25.28 | MNNI | N |
> |  8 |     8 | nickel     |    18.33 | ARAS | A |
> |  9 |     9 | infinity   |    66.64 | DYGD | D |
> | 10 |    10 | spas       |    83.77 | BIIR | I |
> | 11 |    11 | #ERR       |  108.106 | HSSG | S |
> | 12 | 15(1) | rheometer  |    89.91 | ACPA | A |
> | 13 |    13 | adenosine  |  114.103 | FLLR | L |
> | 14 |  2(3) | olelbis    |    71.94 | LUPU | U |
> | 15 |    15 | elementary |  115.101 | MCMD | M |
> | 16 |    16 | sodium     |     3.22 | LITI | I |
> | 17 |    17 | creation   |   102.50 | NOSN | N |
> | 18 |    18 | NTIME      |    95.31 | AMGA | A |
> |    | 16(0) |            |          |      |   |
> |    |       |            |          | ZNBK | ? |
> |    |       |            | nitrogen |      |   |
> ```

Part 2

> The double letters spell: **SODAVANADISALUMINA**
>  soda (sodium) vanadis (vanadium) alumina (aluminium)

Answer

> The element symbols spell **naval**

**Abnormal Appellations**
I've noticed that

> the number of letters in each word match the corresponding element

Comment: Congratulations, your solution for Weird Weights is correct.

Comment: Sorry I’m late, but the solution for Incorrect Integers is also correct. Now for the meta!

Answer (score 15):

**Abnormal Appellations**

> As4s4hetic has observed that the names of the elements in the periodic table in the puzzle and in the actual periodic table have the same length. There is no alternative name for element 11, which is sodium.
>
>  The chemical symbols (H, He, Li, ...) are abbreviations of the element names. Find the positions of the letters of these abbreviations in the name and take the corresponding letters from the names given here. (The symbol for sodium is Na from the Latin name *natrium*, but neither N nor A are in sodium, hence the error.)
>
> ```
>         Hydrogen        Titanium        t.......
>         HElium          HExose          he....
>         LIthium         SOrbose         so.....
>         BEryllium       LUminance       lu.......
>         Boron           Table           t....
>         Carbon          Iodine          i.....
>         Nitrogen        Ostinatn        o.......
>         Oxygen          Nickel          n.....
>         Flourine        Infinity        i.......
>         NEon            SPas            sp..
>         sodium          #error
>         MaGnesium       RhEometer       r.e......
>         ALuminium       ADenosine       ad.......
>         SIlicon         OLelbis         ol.....
>         Phosphorus      Elementary      e.........
>         Sulfur          Sodium          s.....
>         ChLorine        CrEation        c.e.....
>         ARgon           NTime           nt...
> ```
>
> The letters spell: **The solution is preadolescent.**

Comment: Congrats, this answer is also correct